# String that contains first letters of words in another String

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
let string = "This is my sentence"
```

I am looking to get this as a result: "TIMS"

I am struggling with swift and strings for some reason

```
class func getStringOfStartingLetter(str:String) -> String{
        var firstCharacters: NSMutableString = NSMutableString()
        let words: [AnyObject] = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        for word in words   {
            if word.length() > 0 {
                let firstLetter: String = word.substringToIndex(1)
                firstCharacters.appendString(firstLetter.uppercaseString)
                }
        }
        return firstCharacters as String
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let str = "This is my sentence"

var strArr = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    .map() {
        $0.characters.first ?? " "
    }.reduce("") {
        initVal, obj in
        "\(initVal)\(obj)"
    }
print("Arr : \(strArr)")
```

You could do it even like that:

```
var a = "This is my sentence".characters.split(" ")
    .map() {
        $0.first! // Or thanks to @EricD use more safeties way: $0.first ?? " "
}
```

Comment: @Greg can u post answer in objective C?

Comment: @bhavinramani map, filter and reduce are only Swift functions, to do it with Objective-C you most use different approach.

Comment: Be careful, the second version will crash for empty strings because of the force-unwrapped `.first!`.

Answer (score 1):

for Objective-c i have

```
NSMutableString * firstCharacters = [NSMutableString string];
    NSArray * words = [@"this is my sentence" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    for (NSString * word in words) {
      if ([word length] > 0) {
        NSString * firstLetter = [word substringToIndex:1];
        [firstCharacters appendString:[firstLetter uppercaseString]];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice extension for `String`:

```
extension String {

    func uppercasedFirstLetters() -> String {

        let arrayOfWords = self.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

        let firstLetters: [String] = arrayOfWords.map {

            if let character = $0.characters.first {
                return String(character)
            }
            return ""
        }

        return firstLetters.joinWithSeparator("").uppercaseString
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let outputString = "This is my string".uppercasedFirstLetters() //TIMS
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution !! i appreciate it !!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
let str = "This is my sentence"

var res = str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").reduce("") {
    if let character = $1.characters.first {
        return $0 + String(character).uppercaseString
    }
    return $0
}

print(res)
```